# using nil or [] on rails 2.3.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've a strange situation with my rails application (2.3.8)

I want to assign a **no nil** value to some variable in my controller, so I wrote this code:

```
@myValue = session[:value] or []
```

In my view I wrote:

```
<%= @myvalue.size %>
```

When I display my page, I have a nil error.

I've tried the nil or [] in the IRB and I get the []. So my question is if anyone know why is working different in rails?

P.S.: The only gem that I'm using is cell version 3.3.3.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idiom is to do `session[:value] || []`, using `||`, not `or`. You can also try `session[:value].to_a`. This works because `nil.to_a` becomes `[]`.

Answer (score 4):

The 'or' keyword has too low a precedence for this code to work. Use '||' instead. To demonstrate the point:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > a = nil or true; a
 => nil 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > a = nil || true; a
 => true
```

Answer (score 3):

It's an order of operations thing.

`@myValue = (session[:value] or [])` will work.  I believe `@myValue = session[:value] or []` is interpreted as `(@myValue = session[:value]) or []`.  But @myValue = session[:value] || [] worked too without parens.  `||` has higher precedence than `or`.